# Cannot read a single byte from AudioInputStream

Tags: java, audio

I tried to change the sampling rate of a wav file by using the [javax.sound library.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html)

After implementing my wished methods i tried it out, and it worked! 
But the `.wav` file which was created is only a couple of bytes large. To be exact its only 2.090 Byte from originally ~ 50 MB

The problem is, that Java can't read a single byte from my opened AudioInputStream.

FYI, the used file is a product of converting a mp3 file with JLayer. It works fine, there is  no problem with JLayer but I suppose its better if I post my whole sourcecode. Note : I used many System.out.printlns for logging.

So at first I import all needed librarys, as you can see I also imported JLayer.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javazoom.jl.converter.Converter;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;

public class MyConverter {

    private static AudioInputStream lowResAis = null;
    private static AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
```

**After setting those global constants I was writing my main and preselected a demo file for testing purpose.**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyConverter converterdemo = new MyConverter();
        String wavfilepath = "C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Second Nature.wav";
        File f = new File(wavfilepath);
        converterdemo.convertMp3toWav("C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Second Nature.mp3", "C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\Desktop\\Second Nature.wav");
        converterdemo.compressWavFile(wavfilepath);
        converterdemo.writeToSoundFile(f);
        System.out.println("Everything worked!");
    }
```

**This is my converting method**

```
public void convertMp3toWav(String sourcefilename, String targetfilename){
        Converter con = new Converter();
        try {
            con.convert(sourcefilename, targetfilename);
            System.out.println("Wav File converted!");
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            this.showOptionPane("Could not convert by using JLayer!");
        }
    }
```

**The converting method is fine (trust me there is no problem with the audio file), but here is the method, about which I am worrying a little bit**

After adding this line: `System.out.println(AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(audioInputStream).getByteLength());`

I am getting the following Error:`java.io.IOException: cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1`

I cannot read from my own Stream.

```
public void compressWavFile(String sourcefilename){
        try {
            InputStream musicfile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourcefilename));
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicfile);
            AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            AudioFormat outDataFormat = new AudioFormat((float) 22000.0,
                    (int) 16, (int) 1, true, false);
            if(AudioSystem.isConversionSupported(outDataFormat, format)){
                System.out.println("Conversion Supported!");
                lowResAis = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outDataFormat, audioInputStream);
            }
            System.out.println("low res created!");
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            this.showOptionPane("Audio File not Supported!"); e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**I purposely did not use try with resource, because of some sorcery the newly created `AudioInputStream` is also closed after closing the original `audioInputStream` which is now a static variable.**

```
public void writeToSoundFile(File out){
        if(AudioSystem.isFileTypeSupported( AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, lowResAis)){
            try {
                AudioSystem.write(lowResAis,  AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, out);
                System.out.println("New wav file written!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                this.showOptionPane("Could not write to new Audio File!");
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("closing stream!");
            lowResAis.close();
            audioInputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.showOptionPane("Could not close Audio Stream!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**This last bit is only there to write the newly created `AudioInputStream` to a given `File`. I also dont think that anything could go wrong here.**

I really think that there is a problem with my AudioInputStreams because thats the only point where something could go wrong.

EDIT:

I added a new "showOptionPane" method to stay `thread safe` all the time.

```
private void showOptionPane(String msg){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't put JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...) in a catch block unless you are certain that the entire writeToSoundFile(...) is being ran on the Swing UI thread!

Comment: Why shouldnt I ? Its the same thing, as if i would run System.out.println(); Also as i mentioned it is just for logging purpose and will be removed, when complete

Comment: It is not the same thing as System.out.println(...) because it raises a Window, using the Swing library.  The Swing library is not thread safe, so drawing with it when not on the UI thread can cause corruption of the UI state.  This is the reason that all Swing tutorials start with embedding the drawing calls in SwingUtilities.invokeLater(....).  You can invoke later your JOptionPane if you like, but calling it from the non-UI thread is wrong in every situation.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html for more details.

Comment: Okay, I think its fixed now, after reading about the threading in Swing and Event Dispatch Threads.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a pet peeve of mine, as I just fixed nearly 100 similar bugs at work.  They eventually caused enough issues to lockup the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a bug with the `AudioSystem.write` Framework. I tried to write to the same file i was getting the source stream from. Because of some kind of witchcraft `AudioSystem` itself does not create a memory backup of the `stream`. So you can only write your `AudioInputStream` to a different File.

Editing `AudioSystem.write(lowResAis, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, out);`

and changing it to something like `"mysounddemo.wav"` worked pretty well, as long at it has a different name than the `sourcefilestream`.

To achieve the result I wanted, I just moved the temporary file and replaced it with the existing file

`Files.move(Paths.get(appdatapath), Paths.get(wavfilepath), REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an audio pro, but after looking around it seems that the error message is making a bit more sense.

Audio is not exactly a byte stream, but a frame stream; where the entire frame is meant to be loaded into the playback system as it represents the output or input values at one moment in time.

This framework seems to be optimized to read frames.  As such, it likely intends for you to read one or more frames with the getBytes(...) method where you specify a rather large byte buffer to have multiple frames written into.  Apparently it doesn't track sub-frame loading, as using a part of a frame doesn't make sense from an audio perspective.

If you can adjust the frame size to 1, you might read your single byte; but, you couldn't compress it.  The compression routines compress whole frames against each other.  So I recommend you read out one whole frame minimally, unless the point is to walk each byte in a frame.

If the point is to walk the bytes, then I'd avoid treating it like audio, and would treat it just like a byte stream.

So it would seem that your approach might have to change to a frame centric approach, as that's the smallest unit of audio that most audio frameworks handle.

Comment: No the frame size is right. Double channel was 4 bytes per frame and single channel is 2 byte per frame. But I found a solution to get it working. Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: `PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian` this was the audio format before converting. `PCM_SIGNED 22000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian` and this one after. So i think my old converter [dBpowerAMP](http://www.chip.de/downloads/dBpowerAMP-Music-Converter_13008294.html) is obsolete, but the thing that is mocking be is the quality. Both files, one from my program and the other from the buyable softare, have the exact same size, but I think there is no way to measure if they both have the same "quality".

Comment: Well, I think it will depend on how you define quality.  One is pushing more frames per minute, one has more channels, and one has more information per frame.  About the only thing they share is the resolution of the measurement.  Which aspect of quality matters to you?  Dynamic response?  Then a high Hz will be important.  Ability to differentiate between notes?  Then a high bit value matters.  Two channels of sound (important for stereo)?  Then you can't go mono.  I'd say the only reason you see so little difference is probably because you are playing the exact same channel, in both ears.